# Can't use GenericForeignKey in django 1.8.4

Tags: django

I have following models,

```
class Book:
    title = model.CharField(...)

class Article:
    title = model.CharField(...)

class Rating:
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, blank=True, null=True)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    node = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

where `Rating` can contain book or article.

I want django admin to show a single form to edit rating and a give user a choice field to select if he wants to add article or news instead of content-type or object-id, so the user can add book or article in a single form.

I tried using `GenericTabularInline` but I want the user (admin) to have a choice field to select if he wants to add article or book and accordingly the form should change.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use. But just import

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic
```

and then in place of

```
node = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

use

```
node = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```